# How do I connect last two points on a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This is my code on jupyter notebook so far and I'm wondering if I could get point 1 and point 8 connected?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data.txt")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot(x="Eastings", y="Northings", ax=ax)
data.plot.scatter(x="Eastings", y="Northings", ax=ax)

station_list = data["Station"].values.tolist()
x = data["Eastings"].values.tolist()
y = data["Northings"].values.tolist()


for i, txt in enumerate(station_list):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), size=10, xytext=(1,5), ha='center', textcoords='offset points')
```

This is what it looks like right now.
[image]

Comment: One way is to place a copy of the first row of your dataframe at its bottom and run the plot command on that. Otherwise, you can use a second plot command only using the first and last points.

Comment: Perhaps matplotlib Path is something that solves your problem https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect first and last point with `plot()`.

```py
data.plot(x="Eastings", y="Northings", ax=ax, color='b')
data.plot.scatter(x="Eastings", y="Northings", ax=ax)

ax.plot(data.iloc[[0, -1]]['Eastings'], data.iloc[[0, -1]]['Northings'], color='b')
```

[image]